# How to install OpenCV 2.2 on OSX 10.5 32-bit for ActivePython 2.7?

Tags: python, opencv, macports, homebrew, activepython

The title is the whole question.

- I have tried homebrew with the --build32 option
- I have tried macports
- I have tried downloading the source file and compiling from scratch.

All the above install perfectly with no issues. However -- after tracking down the correct cv.so files from the various installations and moving them to the correct /site-packages/ directory for the version of Python I want to use OpenCV with, and ensuring that it is correctly in the PYTHONPATH -- I perpetually get this error:

```
ActivePython 2.7.1.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb  7 2011, 11:33:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import cv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Again, this is after I have exhaustively tried to find a 32-bit version. I searched the OpenCV site and could not find any links to a 32-bit specific source file of version 2.2. When I monitored it during the from-scratch installation, I noted that it was correctly passing around the arch i386 options during configure and make and compiling (as it should since it should be detecting that my system architecture is 32-bit).

I'm really at a loss. Any ideas? Bear in mind that I am specifically trying to get version 2.2 of OpenCV to work specifically with ActivePython version 2.7 of Python. I have OpenCV 2.1 working with Python 2.6.6, but I just updated my work computer to use OpenCV 2.2 with ActivePython 2.7 in Ubuntu and I want to be able to share things smoothly between that computer and my home computer. For the stuff I am doing, having the newest OpenCV is significant.

---

Okay, so here are my exact steps:

(1) Extract the OpenCV source to the directory ~/OpenCV-2.2.0/
(2) Run cmake, use gedit to add the architectures string mentioned above, then run sudo make followed by sudo make install. Here's the output of the later two steps:

```
new-host:OpenCV-2.2.0 ely$ sudo make
-- Extracting svn version, please wait...
-- SVNVERSION: 
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 40 (400)
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   package 'libdc1394' not found
--     Use INCLUDE: /Users/ely/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-- IPP detected: 
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Parsing 'cvconfig.h.cmake'
-- 
-- General configuration for opencv 2.2.0 =====================================
-- 
--     Built as dynamic libs?:    ON
--     Compiler:                  
--     C++ flags (Release):         -Wall -pthread  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -DNDEBUG 
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -Wall -pthread  -g  -O0 -ggdb3 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG 
--     Linker flags (Release):     
--     Linker flags (Debug):       
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     Cocoa:                     1
-- 
--   Image I/O: 
--     JPEG:                      build
--     PNG:                       build
--     TIFF:                      build
--     JPEG 2000:                 build
--     OpenEXR:                   NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:                   QTKit
-- 
--   Interfaces: 
--     Python:                    ON
--     Python interpreter:        /usr/local/bin/python2.7
--     Python numpy:              YES
--     Use IPP:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                  No
--     Use Eigen2:                NO
-- 
--   Documentation: 
--     Build PDF                  NO
--     Doxygen HTMLs              NO
-- 
--     Install path:              /usr/local
-- 
--     cvconfig.h is in:          /Users/ely/OpenCV-2.2.0
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/ely/OpenCV-2.2.0
[  4%] Built target libtiff
[  6%] Built target zlib
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a
[  6%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch
[  6%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 40%] Built target opencv_lapack
[ 42%] Built target opencv_core
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 43%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.a
[ 43%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 43%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_imgproc_Release.gch
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 47%] Built target opencv_imgproc
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 48%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.a
[ 48%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 48%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_highgui_Release.gch
[ 48%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 52%] Built target libjasper
[ 57%] Built target libjpeg
[ 59%] Built target libpng
[ 61%] Built target opencv_highgui
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp
[ 61%] Building CXX object modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp.a
[ 61%] Built target opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp
[ 61%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_calib3d_Release.gch
[ 61%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_calib3d
[ 62%] Built target opencv_calib3d
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_features2d_pch_dephelp.a
[ 62%] Built target opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp
[ 62%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_features2d_Release.gch
[ 63%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_features2d
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_flann_pch_dephelp
[ 63%] Building CXX object modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_flann_pch_dephelp.a
[ 63%] Built target opencv_flann_pch_dephelp
[ 63%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_flann_Release.gch
[ 63%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_flann
[ 63%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 65%] Built target opencv_features2d
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_video_pch_dephelp
[ 65%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_video_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_video_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_video_pch_dephelp.a
[ 65%] Built target opencv_video_pch_dephelp
[ 65%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_video_Release.gch
[ 65%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_video
[ 67%] Built target opencv_video
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp
[ 67%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_legacy_pch_dephelp.a
[ 67%] Built target opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp
[ 67%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_legacy_Release.gch
[ 68%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_legacy
[ 76%] Built target opencv_legacy
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Building CXX object modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_contrib_pch_dephelp.a
[ 77%] Built target opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_contrib_Release.gch
[ 77%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_contrib
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_ml_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_ml_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_ml_pch_dephelp.a
[ 77%] Built target opencv_ml_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_ml_Release.gch
[ 77%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ml
[ 79%] Built target opencv_ml
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 79%] Building CXX object modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp.a
[ 79%] Built target opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 79%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_objdetect_Release.gch
[ 79%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_objdetect
[ 80%] Built target opencv_objdetect
[ 81%] Built target opencv_contrib
[ 81%] Built target opencv_python
[ 81%] Built target opencv_haartraining_engine
[ 81%] Built target opencv_createsamples
[ 81%] Built target opencv_haartraining
[ 82%] Built target opencv_performance
[ 83%] Built target opencv_traincascade
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_gpu_pch_dephelp.a
[ 83%] Built target opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp
[ 83%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_gpu_Release.gch
[ 83%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_gpu
[ 86%] Built target opencv_gpu
[ 86%] Built target opencv_ts
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_pch_dephelp
[ 86%] Building CXX object tests/cv/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_test_pch_dephelp.a
[ 86%] Built target opencv_test_pch_dephelp
[ 86%] Generating cvtest.h.gch/opencv_test_Release.gch
[ 86%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test
[ 94%] Built target opencv_test
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp
[ 94%] Building CXX object tests/cxcore/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.a
[ 94%] Built target opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp
[ 94%] Generating cxcoretest.h.gch/opencv_test_core_Release.gch
[ 95%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_core
[ 97%] Built target opencv_test_core
[ 98%] Built target opencv_test_ml
[100%] Built target opencv_test_gpu

new-host:OpenCV-2.2.0 ely$ sudo make install
[  4%] Built target libtiff
[  6%] Built target zlib
[  6%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 40%] Built target opencv_lapack
[ 42%] Built target opencv_core
[ 43%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 47%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 48%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 48%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 52%] Built target libjasper
[ 57%] Built target libjpeg
[ 59%] Built target libpng
[ 61%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 61%] Built target opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp
[ 61%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_calib3d
[ 62%] Built target opencv_calib3d
[ 62%] Built target opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp
[ 63%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_features2d
[ 63%] Built target opencv_flann_pch_dephelp
[ 63%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_flann
[ 63%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 65%] Built target opencv_features2d
[ 65%] Built target opencv_video_pch_dephelp
[ 65%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_video
[ 67%] Built target opencv_video
[ 67%] Built target opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp
[ 68%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_legacy
[ 76%] Built target opencv_legacy
[ 77%] Built target opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_contrib
[ 77%] Built target opencv_ml_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ml
[ 79%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 79%] Built target opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 79%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_objdetect
[ 80%] Built target opencv_objdetect
[ 81%] Built target opencv_contrib
[ 81%] Built target opencv_python
[ 81%] Built target opencv_haartraining_engine
[ 81%] Built target opencv_createsamples
[ 81%] Built target opencv_haartraining
[ 82%] Built target opencv_performance
[ 83%] Built target opencv_traincascade
[ 83%] Built target opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp
[ 83%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_gpu
[ 86%] Built target opencv_gpu
[ 86%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 86%] Built target opencv_test_pch_dephelp
[ 86%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test
[ 94%] Built target opencv_test
[ 94%] Built target opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp
[ 95%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_core
[ 97%] Built target opencv_test_core
[ 98%] Built target opencv_test_ml
[100%] Built target opencv_test_gpu
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cvwimage.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxeigen.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/cxmisc.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/highgui.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv/ml.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/internal.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/wimage.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/allocator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/autotuned_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/composite_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/general.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/ground_truth.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/index_testing.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kmeans_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/linear_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/logger.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/matrix.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/nn_index.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/object_factory.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/random.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/result_set.h 
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/sampling.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/saving.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/simplex_downhill.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/timer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/blobtrack.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/legacy/streams.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_haartraining
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_performance
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/devmem2d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/matrix_operations.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/stream_accessor.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/haartraining.htm
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/CMakeLists.txt
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/license.txt
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/packaging.txt
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/README.txt
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/opencv.jpg
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/opencv-logo.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/opencv-logo2.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/opencv.pdf
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/opencv_cheatsheet.pdf
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/pattern.pdf
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/papers/algo_tracking.pdf
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/papers/camshift.pdf
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/papers/avbpa99.ps
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/vidsurv/Blob_Tracking_Modules.doc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/vidsurv/Blob_Tracking_Tests.doc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/doc/vidsurv/TestSeq.doc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml  
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml

new-host:OpenCV-2.2.0 ely$ python
ActivePython 2.7.1.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb  7 2011, 11:33:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>>> exit()
```

And just to be sure, based on the Python path that it found during the install, I tried:

```
new-host:OpenCV-2.2.0 ely$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7
ActivePython 2.7.1.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb  7 2011, 11:33:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

It seems that no matter what I do, I get this architecture error. I've installed OpenCV straight through, no problems, with and without this architecture string specifier in the CMakeCache.txt, and both ways result in the same error.

I appreciate the help, any other ideas?

Comment: Well, without activepython, your installation would be really simple (`port install opencv +python27`), and you're complaining about how hard it is to track down your error - doesn't seem like it's a really nice distribution.

Comment: I didn't suggest you do that and try to use that with activepython or the system python in /usr/bin, i merely pointed out that it's a lot less painless if you are using packages made for each other (i.e. macports opencv + macports python).

Answer (score 0):

I successfully built OpenCV 2.2 with ActivePython 2.7.

To build for 32-bit you need to:

1. add `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=i386` to your CMakeCache.txt (right after running `cmake`)
2. Re-run `cmake`

If you need the full build instructions I followed, let me know ... I'll update this answer.